# World space to camera space

Tags: math, matrix, 3d

I am confused on how to convert world space coordinates to camera coordinates.

My current understanding is that I would need to calculate the camera space vector  where

n = eyepoint - lookat

u = up(0,1,0) X n(normalized)

v = n X u

Then once I have < U, V, N > would I simply multiply each point by ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets assume:

- **Eye position** is **E**=(e_x, e_y, e_z),
- **Viewing direction** is **D**=(d_x, d_y, d_z)
- **Up-Vector** is **UP**=(up_x, up_y, up_z)

Now first construct an orthonormal frame:

- R = D X UP
- U = R X D
- Now normalize D,R,U and you have an orthonormal frame for the camera (D,R,U)

In order to transform the global coord frame into the cam-coord frame you can apply the following matrix **M_R**:

> - | R_x, R_y, R_z, 0 |
> - | U_x, U_y, U_z, 0 |
> - | -D_x, -D_y, -D_z, 0|
> - | 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0|

If your cam is not positioned at global origin you also have to apply a translation **M_T**:

> - | 1, 0, 0, -e_x |
> - | 0, 1, 0, -e_y |
> - | 0, 0, 1, -e_z|
> - | 0, 0, 0, 1|

In the end your complete transformation matrix from global to cam-coords is:

- **M** = M_R * M_T

> - | R_x, R_y, R_z, (R dot -E) |
> - | U_x, U_y, U_z, (U dot -E) |
> - | -D_x, -D_y, -D_z, (D dot E)|
> - | 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0|

Comment: btw. the matrix <U,V,N> you mentioned in your post corresponds to (M_R)^-1=(M_R)^T in my post and is the inverse transformation...from cam-coords to global coords.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been stuck on this for a bit and your explanation was very clear and easy to follow. +1

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in previous post

this matrix

```
| R_x, R_y, R_z, (R dot -E) |
| U_x, U_y, U_z, (U dot -E) |
| -D_x, -D_y, D_z, (D dot E)|
| 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0|
```

should be(I test it in openGL, this one is right)

```
| R_x, R_y, R_z, (R dot -E) |
| U_x, U_y, U_z, (U dot -E) |
| -D_x, -D_y, -D_z, (D dot E)|
| 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0|
```

Comment: The negative in D_z depends on whether the system uses the right or left hand rule. OpenGL uses the right handed system, which is why you had to modify your matrix (i.e. negative z points into the screen in a right handed screen)