# Move camera gluLookAt

Tags: c, opengl, glu

With this instruction gluLookAt:

```
gluLookAt( p1, p2, p3, l1, l2, l3, u1, u2, u3 );
```

How can I move the camera one unit to the left, keeping the direction of looking at the same point?

Apparently i cant just do p1-1, because its moving 1 in the global space, but i need to move the camera in the camera space, just with the information of the instruction above.

A found in a search that i could found the right vector and do this:

```
right = u * dir (normalized)

p = p - right
l = l - right
```

But i cant understand why or even if this works...

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832505/world-space-to-camera-space

Answer (score 1):

You have to decrement p1 **and** l1.

**p** specifies the position of the eye point and **l** the position of the reference point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying the position of the camera you should do the same changes with the target's coords.

Answer (score 0):

Whether your question is the same as that rotate around y-axis clockwise for one unit left?

Comment: It is usually unwise to make an answer that is actually a question. What has been said around here also applies: leaving comments is more appropriate for that.